# How to send Ctrl-C control character or terminal hangup message to child process?

Tags: c, posix, pty

I have a child process which runs in a pseudo terminal. The parent process does not run as root, but the child process does, through su or sudo. Because of this it is not possible to send a signal to the child process to force it to exit. I want to force it to exit by one of these means:

- emulating a Ctrl-C.
- emulating a terminal hangup.

How do I do either of these? I already have a pty master fd, and I've tried something like this:

```
write(master, &termios.c_cc[VINTR], 1)
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't know if this will work with your program/pty, but what I do since I'm running bash, and bash takes ^C as SIGINT by default [I think?] is make a char that contains a hex code: ( 0x03 for ^C ) and then write it to my pty with:
 
    write( m_nMaster, &ctrlC, sizeof( ctrlC ) );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually went with the following solution:

After forking, instead of exec'ing sudo immediately, I exec() a helper child process instead, which in turn forks and execs sudo and calls waitpid on it. So the process hierarchy looks like this:

```
original process          <---- runs as user
  |
  +-- helper process      <---- runs as user, session leader,
         |                      has own pty, in pty's foreground process group
         |
         +--- sudo        <---- runs as root
```

By killing the helper process, the pty does not have a foreground process anymore. This will cause the OS to send SIGHUP to the entire foreground process group, regardless of the user, so sudo is SIGHUP'ed too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that if you truly have a pty (unless you mean something else by pseudo terminal), that all you have to do is send a Control-C to that FD.  As evidence of this, I submit the following code in Python (but fairly close to the C required to do it):

```
import pty, os, sys, time

pid, fd = pty.fork()
if pid == 0:
   os.execv('/bin/sh', ['/bin/sh', '-c',
         'while true; do date; sleep 1; done'])
   sys.exit(0)
time.sleep(3)
os.write(fd, '^C')
print 'results:', os.read(fd, 1024)
```

This forks a process under a pty, which runs an infinite loop printing the
date.  Then the parent waits 3 seconds and sends a control-C.

This results in the following output:

```
guin:/tmp$ time python /tmp/foo
results: Fri Feb  5 08:28:09 MST 2010
Fri Feb  5 08:28:10 MST 2010
Fri Feb  5 08:28:11 MST 2010

python /tmp/foo  0.02s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 3.042 total
guin:/tmp$
```

It ran just over 3 seconds, printed out the date 3 times, and exited.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not working the way you describe. Writing the literal string "^C" does not send an interrupting control character. The reason it seems to work is that when the python process dies, the process on the other end of the pty gets a SIGHUP (not a SIGINT). If you remove the `os.write` it behaves the same way. But if you `os.write(fd,"\x03")` a real SIGINT is delivered. You can verify this by running the test under `strace -f`.

Comment: Why would this print anything to stdout? The forked process has its own stdout which is totally different from the original, right? When running this here I get "results: b'^C'". Maybe this was different in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `ioctl` to insert the interrupt character instead of `write`. Unfortunately the mechanism for this does not seem to be portable. For linux it looks this might work:

```
ioctl(master, TIOCSTI, &termios.c_cc[VINTR]);
```

Comment: I get a "permission denied"/"operation not permitted" error. If I run the process as root then I get "operation timed out".

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to achieve this:

- From the child process, trap the SIGCHLD signal and handle it, you could _exit(0) to end the child process
- There's a program called [ptree](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ptree+1). You could cheat this by doing it this way...in pseudocode:

```
obtain the parent's pid.
using _popen("ptree %d", parent_pid)
for each entry of child process
system ("kill -1 %d", child_process_pid)
```

There the two that comes to mind...sorry if its not of further help to you,

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: He can't directly signal the child because it is running under a different effective uid.

Comment: @caf: hmmm....can you answer this? imagine if the child process is running on a pseudo terminal, take this under a linux example... if a binary file was to be cat'ted to the pseudo terminal say /dev/pty4 where the child process is at, would that cause a terminal hangup? i.e. cat binary_file > /dev/pty4

Comment: No, why would it? It will just deliver those bytes to the master side of the pseudo terminal pair.

Comment: @caf: Ok. I thought it would cause the terminal's shell process to hang and henceforth forced to log off...that's what I was thinking...

Answer (score 0):

Closing the master should signal a hangup to the controlling process group of the slave.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd check is if you need to make it the controlling terminal on the slave side. It turns out this is [more complex](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.3) than I remember, with ptys possibly not becoming controlling by default. That link is for Linux, other systems should do one or the other depending on their SysV vs. BSD-ness, but it looks like the TIOCSCTTY is a good bet to try.

Secondly, I'd check if you're setting ISIG in your termios; if not, VINTR and VQUIT won't work.

Of course, if the other end is catching SIGINT and SIGQUIT, you will have other issues.