# Can I interact with an open vt from a c program?

Tags: c, linux, bash

Assume I have a state machine started as root to run one and only one program in a given reserved vt. The first call I use something like:

```
execl("/usr/bin/openvt", "/usr/bin/openvt", "-c 12", "-f", "-- su auser /home/auser/sbin/ascript.sh", (char *) 0);
```

Is the only way to find the PID's of all of the children (The shell script, the calls, etc) to search ps aux for the PID's that are generated on that vt (tty12) and kill them, as fork only will hold the PID of the openvt command which pretty much dies after the new vt is open?
Or is there a slick way to send a SIGINT to a known vt (i.e., /dev/vcs12 dev/tty12)?

Comment: `-w     wait for command to complete.` Is this helpful? Maybe see this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195885/how-to-send-ctrl-c-control-character-or-terminal-hangup-message-to-child-process

Answer (score 1):

The `-t tty` option to ps may be what you are looking for...

```
kill -INT `ps -t vcs12 -o pid=`
```

or, in a sh/bash-specific way:

```
kill -INT $(ps -t vcs12 -o pid=)
```